# Pivot multiple rows in initial table

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have a table which i would like to pivot to show how many categories a person is affiliated with...

[image]

I would like to pivot this to show:

[image]

There are a lot more members and categories but the theory i believe should be the same.

I have attempted this however it only shows the first line for each.

Thanks in advance

Will

Comment: Dont put image. put it as a content. it will be easier to copy the names, values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Will, this is the logic you need. Basically a pivot function on the column of interest.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (RegNo varchar(20), Category varchar(20), Number int)
INSERT INTO  @tbl
SELECT 'R1050162', 'Gym', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'R1050162', 'Personal Trainer', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'R0093126', 'Group Exercise', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'R0143614', 'Yoga Teacher', 1 


SELECT * 
    FROM
@tbl
PIVOT
(
SUM(Number)
FOR Category IN ([Gym], [Personal Trainer], [Group Exercise], [Yoga Teacher]

)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Output is below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, from my original attemps it seems the unions were what i hadn't added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use just sum the Number field in PIVOT function and for numerous categories get a category list:

```
DECLARE @categories AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @your_query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @categories = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Category) 
            FROM your_table 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT RegNo, ' + @categories + ' from 
            (
                SELECT RegNo, Category, Number FROM your_table) tab
                PIVOT
                (
                  SUM(Number) 
                 FOR Category IN (' + @categories + ')
            ) p iv
            ORDER BY piv.RegNo'

execute(@your_query)
```